# How would I get the execution time of copy_from() function when using psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Now I am using psycopg2 to connect to postgresql and use the copy function to load the local txt data into the database.

Currently my code is as follows:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection, LoggingCursor
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyLoggingCursor(LoggingCursor):
    def execute(self, query, vars=None):
        self.timestamp = time.time()
        return super(MyLoggingCursor, self).execute(query, vars)

    def callproc(self, procname, vars=None):
        self.timestamp = time.time()
        return super(MyLoggingCursor, self).callproc(procname, vars)

class MyLoggingConnection(LoggingConnection):
    def filter(self, msg, curs):
        return msg + "   %d ms" % int((time.time() - curs.timestamp) * 1000)

    def cursor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('cursor_factory', MyLoggingCursor)
        return LoggingConnection.cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)

db_settings = {
    "database": "gps_stat",
    "user": "user",
    "password": "test@123",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 26000
}

target_txt = "test.txt"
table_name = 'gps_base'

start_time=time.time()
conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_factory=MyLoggingConnection, **db_settings)
conn.initialize(logger)
cur = conn.cursor('cursor_unique_name', cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
f = open(target_txt, 'r')
cur.copy_from(f, table_name, sep=',')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
f.close()
print("Time：{}ms".format(time.time()-start_time))
```

But the `MyLoggingConnection` does not meet my needs.

There are about 200 million pieces of data in the test_txt. After the above program runs, it prints `Time: 2000ms`, but in fact I waited about 20 minutes to get the result of `Time: 2000ms`.

What can I do to get the real execution time of the copy_from() function?

Comment: What happens when you run it?  What is unreal about the current execution time?

Comment: Something like?: `start_time = time.time() cur.copy_from(f, table_name, sep=',') end_time = time.time() elapsed_time = end_time -start_time1`. Or look at the Postgres log to get the timing.

Comment: There are about 200 million pieces of data in the test_txt. After the above program runs, it prints `Time: 2000ms`, but in fact I waited about 20 minutes to get the result of `Time: 2000ms`.@jjanes

Comment: Is the Python code running on the same machine as the database? In other words are you actually connecting to `localhost` or remotely?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, the above Python code runs directly on the server where the Postgresql database is installed and the connection to localhost is valid. The code can correctly load the data into the database, but the elapsed time recorded using `end_time-start_time` seems inaccurate.

Comment: Again look at the Postgres log to see what is actually happening at database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I had same issue and then I have written small program to verify this and came to know this

```
start_time=time.time()

time.sleep(3)

print("Total Time Taken :: {} ms".format(time.time()-start_time))
```

and output is

> Total Time Taken :: 3.010446071624756 ms

It means, time which you are getting is in seconds as I am putting time on sleep for 3 sec. If it is in ms then, result should have been 3000+ ms whereas result is 3.010 which is nothing but sec. I believe your execution is taking total 2000 sec.

happy coding!

Comment: You are right. I mistook python's timestamp as being in milliseconds.